# Use pip package inside Conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am confused about how the packages installed through `pip` and `conda` work together.
What I do know:

- `pip` and `conda` install different package format. What are the implications here except that `pip` can not install the `conda` package format? (which is fine for the purpose of this question since you can always use the appropriate command to install a package; I am interested in the part that follows)

Say, **`package A`** is installed via `pip`; **`package B`** installed via `conda` in an isolated conda environment `custom_env`.
Now, I create a python script, which needs to use both **`package A`** and **`package B`**; I launch it inside the `custom_env`.

**Will the python script have access to **`package A`**?**

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** Will the python script have access to package A?
**Answer:**: It seems no.

..and it makes sense.
I expected conda to guarantee an isolated environment.
But I needed to test this assumption.

**How I tested it:**
1 - pick a package:
e.g: `scipy`

2 - deactivate conda:
`conda deactivate`

3 - check if scipy is installed in pip:
`pip list | grep scipy`
Output:
`scipy                                  0.13.0b1`

4 - activate conda environment:
`conda activate`

5 - check if conda see a scipy package:
`conda list | grep scipy`
Output:
  (empty)

**( Double Check )**
6 - you might have a pip as part of the conda environment,
let's check it too with:
`pip list | grep scipy` (with conda environment activated).
Output:

**( Triple Check )**
7 - I also tried to:
A - import scipy without conda environment ( with pip ) -> success
B - import scipy inside conda environment -> error

[image: scipy inside vs outside conda]