# How to isolate conda environments

Tags: pip, anaconda, virtual-environment

I want to begin development by creating a conda environment, but many packages are only available on pip.
I have 3 virtual environments, base, conda1, and conda2. the problem here is that when I do `pip install package1==1.0` in conda1, its reflecting on conda2 and base. and when i execute `pip intall package2==2.0` in conda2, it reflects in the other 2 virtual environments.

is this expected behavior? if not how do I fix it? I want to properly isolate virtual environments.

I'm developing on windows 11.

Note: I know python's virtualenv package is an option, I want to try doing this with conda.
I've also attached the image of my virtual environments.[conda virtual environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyGaU.png)

environment path for all virtual environments:

```
C:\Users\blahb\anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell_7.3.6.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe;C:\mongosh-1.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Users\blahb\anaconda3;C:\Users\blahb\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\blahb\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\blahb\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\blahb\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\blahb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\blahb\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
```

## Expectation

my expectation what that all packages installed inside a conda environment would be an isolated unit from other conda environments.

according to [Use pip package inside Conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064180/use-pip-package-inside-conda-environment)
packages installed inside a conda environment are only available within that environment and not outside.

if that is so, then maybe my environment setup is screwed up somewhere. How can I begin fixing it?

Comment: When you say `environment path for all virtual environments` does that mean that no matter which env you activate `rcho %PATH%` always returns the same?